# Install 2 or more minor releases of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

We are using VS to build application, including native C++ dlls.

I have a need to investigate possible dependency of some behavior by installing another nimor release. Specifically, I have 15.9.6 now at my desktop, and some other computer has 15.9.11, and I suspect that this may affect the behavior of resulting binaries.

Can I install the part of Visual Studio which performs the C++ build (compiler, standard includes, etc.) alongside with the current version, so that I could use it for building, and the current installation would not be disturbed?

PS: from the "VS installer", when I select "modify" the existing installation and then "Individual components", I can find there:

- VC++ 2017 version 15.4 v14.11 toolset
- VC++ 2017 version 15.5 v14.12 toolset
- VC++ 2017 version 15.6 v14.13 toolset
- VC++ 2017 version 15.7 v14.14 toolset
- VC++ 2017 version 15.8 v14.15 toolset
- VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
- VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 Libs for Spectre (ARM)
- VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 Libs for Spectre (ARM64)
- VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 Libs for Spectre (x86 and x64)

Answer (score 1):

You can install multiple minor versions of the vc2017 tool chain (use the individual packages tab in the visual studio installer and the minor versions of the compiler will be listed).

To use them you have to build from the command line rather than from within VS (afaik the VS IDE can only use the most recent installed minor VC build for the chosen major release). The batch files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build can be used to set up a build environment to use a different minor release of the vc2017 tool set.

run "vcvars32.bat /help" or "vcvars64.bat /help" for details.

Comment: Please see the screenshot in the question, is it that one? It looks like I'd have to upgrade VS anyway, because it lets me select only lower versions. But it can be the way to go. Thank you

Comment: I am blind, screen shots are useless to me, sorry.

Comment: Changed to text. Actually, it seems to be more coarse than that version. I asked my colleague with 15.9.9 and they see same items there.